# How to debug DPDK libraries to diagnose segmentation fault?

Tags: dpdk

I am working with DPDK version 18.11.8 stable on Linux, using a gcc x64 build.

At runtime I get a segmentation fault. Running gdb on the core dump gives this backtrace:

```
#0  0x0000000000f65680 in rte_eth_devices ()
#1  0x000000000048a03a in rte_eth_rx_burst (nb_pkts=7,
rx_pkts=0x7fab40620480, queue_id=0, port_id=<optimized out>)
    at
/opt/dpdk/dpdk-18.08/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_ethdev.h:3825
#2  Socket_poll (ucRxPortId=<optimized out>, ucRxQueId=ucRxQueId at entry=0
'\000', uiMaxNumOfRxFrm=uiMaxNumOfRxFrm at entry=7,
    pISocketListener=pISocketListener at entry=0xf635d0 <FH_gtFrontHaulObj+16>)
    at /data/<snip>/SocketClass.c:2188
#3  0x000000000048b941 in FH_perform (args_ptr=<optimized out>) at
/data/<snip>/FrontHaul.c:281
#4  0x00000000005788e4 in eal_thread_loop ()
#5  0x00007fab419fae65 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#6  0x00007fab4172388d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

So it seems that rte_eth_rx_burst() calls  rte_eth_devices () and that function crashes, presumably because of an illegal memory access. Possibly a hugepages problem?

I want to enable more debug info in DPDK. I am building DPDK using:

```
usertools/dpdk-setup.sh
```

Am I correct in thinking that the build commands in that script use make and I should modify the appropriate:

```
config/defconfig_*
```

file (defconfig_x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc in my case) ?

If so, would these values be appropriate?

```
CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_ETHDEV_DEBUG=y
RTE_LOG_LEVEL=RTE_LOG_DEBUG
RTE_LIBRTE_ETHDEV_DEBUG=y
```

(not sure whether all values should be prefixed by 'CONFIG_'?)

I tried building DPDK using:

```
$ export EXTRA_CFLAGS='-O0 -g'
$ make install T=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc
```

but that gave no extra info in the backtrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: error is identified update is `Fixed and running without crashing now`

using chat room dpdk-debug, we were able to rebuild the libraries and application with proper CFLAGS. Using gdb have identified the probable cause is in rte_eth_rx_burst not being passed with pointer array for mbuf.

Based on the GDB details for frame `1`, it looks the application is not build with the `EXTRA_CFLAGS` (assuming you are using DPDK example Makefile). The right way to build an DPDK application for debugging is to follow the steps as

1. cd [dpdk target folder]
2. make clean
3. make EXTRA_CFLAGS='-O0 -ggdb'
4. cd [application folder]
5. make EXTRA_CFLAGS='-O0 -ggdb'

then use GDB in TUI or non-TUI mode to analyze the error.

note:

1. one of the most common mistakes I commit in rx_burst, is passing *mbuf_array instead of **mbuf_array as the argument.
2. if custom Makefile is used for the application, pass the EXTRA_CFLAGS as `CFLAGS+="-O0 -ggdb"`

Comment: Thanks very much for this info. Unfortunately, the added debug flags haven't added to the backtrace info. And I believe I am specifying **mbuf_array correctly.

Comment: I am surprised, would like to set a chat or debug for the same?

Comment: Yes please, how would I start a chat?

Comment: ok, we can start a chat for debugging to identify why the debug flags via flags is not refelected

Comment: Not sure how to start a chat, so adding a comment here to trigger the automatic process

Comment: can you add yourself to chat room `dpdk-debug`. I have added you

Comment: Hi @DavidA based on debug, it looks like the error was by passing an incorrect argument. The answer shared also highlight the same. If it has solved the issue, please upvote and accept the answer